# send a random generated value to javascript function onclick

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a scenario where i need to pass randomly generated id to the javascript function, but javascript function is not recognizing. Iam using dojo enhanced grid. Below is the code:

```
function(value, rowIndex) {
            var Id = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex).ID;
            alert("ID+ " + Id);//retriving the id value correctly
            return  "<img src=../img/smiley.jpg width=\"20\" height=\"20\" onClick=\"showData(\''+Id +'\')\" class=\"display\">"  ;
        };

<script>
function showData(id){
alert(id);//unable to get the id here..
}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: call `showDate(Id)` function after your working alert. If you want to use `Id` without calling the function you've to put `var Id` outside the function. When you are trying to alert it in the `showData` function you are in another scope. Javascript is also case sensitive so you have to use `Id` instead of `id`.

Comment: @GuyY i cannot call the showDate(Id) function after alert as, i want to have onClick event, when i click on the image that function should be called passing that Id to the javascript function as their i have to process more with that Id. Is their any way to perform.Thanks.

Comment: Don't understand what you exactly mean. But have you already looked at `on` with `lang.hitch`? I use this most of the time when I have scope problems in Dojo..

Comment: @GuyT, thanks. I tried but that does'nt work for me..as i have a enhanced grid so when i click on particular column it has to pass the id of that column to the javascript function, the code is similar to one which i posted above.

Comment: What was you solution? I'm also using the enhanced grid a lot, but the dojo community recommends the `dgrid` or `jqGrid`. The problem is that the `enhancedGrid` has much more features(and I need a lot of them), but it is a bit buggy. I already wrote 4 patches to fit it to my needs(and solve some bugs). 1. Infinity scroll without `JsonRest`. 2. Also do the infinityscroll with arrowdown and pagedown 3. CTRL + space isn't working. 4. When you set `ColumnReordering` to true and you resize a column it will use a wrong column size(in comparison to the headers).

Comment: @GyuT, sorry for late reply, i have passed it as a query string,then it got worked. And yes, enhanced grid has lot of features, but we are using very few out of them..

Answer (score 3):

The quotes in the listener are messed up. I tend to use double quotes for HTML and single for script, and nest as appropriate:

```
return  '<img src="../img/smiley.jpg" width="20" height="20" onclick="showData(\'' + Id + '\');" class="display">';
```

Also, I much prefer to use lower case for all attribute names and to quote all values, not just those that strictly need it.

Finally, variable names starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for constructors so you should use `id` not `Id`.